# Как показать выборочно только объекты имеющие bookmark равный true

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

```
public class Node
        {           
            public bool bookmark { get; set; }

            public ObservableCollection<Node> collection_node { get; set; }
```

.

```
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding collection_node}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name_}">
                                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>

                                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>
```

Одно дерево используется для вывода в 2 местах.

У меня происходит рекурсивный обход с созданием новой коллекции для второго дерева.

Но при редактирования нодов первого дерева нужно изменять и ноды второго.

Поэтому нужно использовать одну коллекцию.

**Можно как-то через Where отфильтровать рекурсивно без создания второй коллекции?** `GLOBAL.node_bookmark.collection_node` `GLOBAL.node.collection_node`

```
TreeB1(null, null);

tw_tree_b.ItemsSource = GLOBAL.node_bookmark.collection_node.Where(t => t.bookmark);

public void TreeB1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeB2(GLOBAL.node.collection_node/*, 0*/);
        }
public void TreeB2(ObservableCollection<Node> node)
        {
            foreach (var i in node)
            {
                if (i.bookmark = true)
                {
                    GLOBAL.node_bookmark.collection_node.Add(i);
                }

                if (i.collection_node.Count != 0)
                {
                    TreeB2(i.collection_node);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Да...............

Comment: Всегда.........(При запуске программы)

Comment: @codename0082016, Вы изменили первоначальную постановку вопроса. Теперь решение не подходит к самому вопросу. :-О !

Comment: @codename0082016 я откатил последнюю правку. если у вас возник новый вопрос - задайте его отдельным вопросом, приведя полный код и дав ссылку на этот вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что collection_node - это коллекция экземпляров класса Node. Почему бы Вам не сделать Where()  после заполнения коллекции.

```
collection_node = collection_node.Where(t => t.Bookmark);
```

Comment: таким способом можно тоже отфильтровать элементы которые содержат true

Comment: Вы правы.Исправил

Comment: А как рекурсивно обойти всё дерево. ? У меня происходит поиск только первого уровня.

Comment: В первоначальном вопросе речь шла только про один уровень. Примените тоже условие к дочерней коллекции после загрузки